# Video not playing in production. Django backend

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to understand how I can have my website properly display - specifically a banner video.

I think the issue relates to Mimetype - It works from my computer but not when served from a server unless the browser is chrome.

This is the website https://consultingpage.herokuapp.com/ .

I assume that the issue is within my settings.py or urls.py - I'll put them below.

Urls.py

```
"""
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from profiles import views as profiles_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', profiles_views.base, name='base'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
and
```

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for alex1 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['consultingpage.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'alex1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'alex1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
    )

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

And the specific HTML in question.

```
div class="video-wrap">
                    <video poster="{% static 'img/videos/3.jpg' %}" preload="auto" loop autoplay muted>
                        <source src="{% static 'img/videos/3.webm' %}" type='video/webm' />
                        <source src="{% static 'img/videos/3.mp4' %}" type='video/mp4' />
                    </video>
                    <div class="video-overlay" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.80);"></div>
                </div>
```

Appreciate the help everyone - Once I have this issue finished I think I've finally made my first website work completely!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console (in the browser)?

Comment: Also, your video works fine for me when I go to your heroku page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video is working fine. If you want to get the audio just remove the `muted` option.

```
<video poster="{% static 'img/videos/3.jpg' %}" preload="auto" loop autoplay>
```

Comment: I should clarify - It doesn't work on all platforms. So for example it is not working in Safari, or Firefox

Comment: for safari you have to use raw format of the video. As in safari html4 video tag doesn't support file url. If it's the only video you are using for static design not dynamically with media you can simple upload the video in github and put the link in your html, just don't forget to add ?raw=true at the end of the url. it will work in safari for sure